# Activate VREF+ pin on STM32L073VBT6

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, keil

I would like to read ADC over STM32L073VBT6. When I try this, I see that the value is always 4095 and does not change (expected to be 0 or close to it). While searching for the error I noticed that there is no voltage on the VREF+ pin. So, I would like to activate the VREF+ pin (STM 21 pin) on the STM32. I know this is active by default, but when I measure on the PCB, I measure the voltage on that pin as 0 Volts. Should this pin always produce a standard voltage? If not, how can I activate this pin via CubeMX or somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

VREF+ is an input pin.

You can connect it to an accurate and stable external reference voltage source that is between 1.65V and Vdda or directly to Vdda, depending on your requirements.

See the reference manual RM0367 for more details of VREF+ and the ADC operation.

In particular, note that if you need to use the DAC, VREF+ should be at least 1.8V.